# sails.js excel user import

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

i'm trying to make a user import page with sails.js and excel module, how im trying to do it is  with the excel module get a xlsx file as json, then sails find the user in the database, if it exists it only updates the user, but if it doesnt exists it creates it, im trying to do it with a for loop, but it only creates the last record in the excel file, here are my user controller and the excel file:

```
module.exports = {
    import: function(req, res){
        var excel = require('excel');
        var count =0;
        var notCreated = 0;
        var created = 0;
        var updated = 0;

        req.file('xlsx').upload({dirname: '../../files/files'}, function onUploadComplete(err, files){
            if(err) return res.serverError(err);
            excel(files[0].fd, function(err, data){
                if(err) throw err;
                for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                    count++;
                    console.log(data[i]);
                    var user = data[i];
                    User.findOne({idClient: user[0]}).exec(function findCB(err, record){
                        if(!record){
                            console.log('Not Found');
                            console.log(user[0]);
                            console.log(user[1]);
                            console.log(user[2]);
                            User.create({idClient: user[0], email: user[1], password: 123456, cargo: user[2]}).exec(function createCB(err, created){
                                if(created){
                                    console.log('User created: '+created.idClient);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                };  
                console.log('-------------- End of file -------------');
            });
        });

        res.json({count: count});

    }

};
```

The excel file:

```
id-client   email           cargo
1111        1111@1111.com   123
1112        1112@1112.com   123
1113        1113@1113.com   123
```

Comment: Have your tried outputting or catching your error on your User.create() to see if something is being caught?

Comment: yes, but it doesnt have errors, it just creates the last user in the excel file

Comment: what is your console output of the above code?